# のです abbreviated to んで？

Tags: grammar, word-choice, abbreviations

> 「いろんな種類あるんで。」

Is this just an abbreviation of のです？ Or is it supposed to be ので？ I’ve seen んで a handful of times so I thought I would ask about it!

Answer (score 4):

This is just ので, as you surmised. Since the sentence ends there, it probably refers to something the speaker said just before this. Here you could translate the ので/んで kind of like the ", you see." in "There's a wide variety (of goods etc), you see.", although in many contexts this would sound weird in English.